# Running an executable command in Java with parameters?

Tags: java, parameters, runtime, executable, exe

So i understand how to use the Runtime command in java pretty well to get an executable to run.  My question is how would i code that to incorporate a parameter such as you would see in the target in a shortcut property, i.e. target: "C:......\notepad.exe" -w.  In what way could I incorporate a parameter such as -w into the Java runtime command.

Answer (score 4):

Use a [ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) and supply the necessary arguments to its constructor:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\path\\to\\notepad.exe", "-w");
```

The first argument is always the application, any other arguments (if present) will be the arguments to add to the application.

You can then call the `start()` method to start it and grab the process object back if you so wish.

Comment: can you help with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43051640/call-an-exe-from-java-with-passing-parameters-with-writing-to-stdout-and-reading ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at ProcessBuilder - http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

This should provide you a relatively fail-safe way to execute with parameters and arguments

Answer (score 0):

You can supply `String[]` to the `exec` method, see [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29). Where the first argument is the command and the next are the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the abovementioned, you can do something like:

```
                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(exeFile.toString() + "params");
```

where exeFile is a File of your executable.

Comment: This isn't a great idea because you have to put the spaces in manually between arguments (causing more potential for errors) and it's not necessarily platform independent.