# Call an exe from Java with passing parameters with writing to stdout and reading from stdin

Tags: java, exe, stdout, stdin, processbuilder

I have read this question:
[Java Programming: call an exe from Java and passing parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5604698/2674303)

And this answer is good enough
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5604756/2674303

But I additionally want to pass parameters to stdin of external process and read from stdout of this process.

How can I do this?

**My efforts**:

main method:

```
public class ProcessBuilderTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_111\\bin\\java",
                "-cp", //class path key
                "C:\\Users\\redwhite\\IdeaProjects\\HelloMyWorld\\out\\production\\HelloMyWorld" , // path to class file of ExternalProcess class 
                "call_external.ExternalProcess"); // fully qualified name
        Process process = pb.start();
        OutputStream processOutputStream = process.getOutputStream();
        IOUtils.write("1" + System.lineSeparator(), processOutputStream);
        InputStream processInputStream = process.getInputStream();
        System.out.println("--1--");
        System.out.println(process.isAlive()); // outputs true
        String result = IOUtils.toString(processInputStream, "UTF-8"); //<-- hangs here
        System.out.println("--2--");
        process.waitFor();
        System.out.println(result); // expect to see processed[1]
    }
}
```

ExternalProcess await **string from stdin** and produce another string to **stdout**:

```
package call_external;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
/**
 * Created by redwhite on 27.03.2017.
 */
public class ExternalProcess {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String input = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("processed[" + input + "]");
    }
}
```

This code hangs.I cannot understand why

Comment: @Reimeus maybe... I don't know way to check it. For this case I added System.lineSeparator() to the end of input

Comment: your code isnt clear. how are the 2 code snippets related? Post a [mcve]

Comment: @Reimeus It is really minimal, complete and so on.In the first part of code I invoke external process.  The code of this process provided in the second code snippet

Comment: @Reimeus new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_111\\bin\\java", "-cp", **"project_folder\\target\\classes package.ExternalProcess"**);

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the `IOUtils` class is and what the `toString()` method is doing. However, a way to read from the `InputStream` is:

```
InputStreamReader isr;
BufferedReader br;

String input = "";
String line;

try {

  isr = new InputStreamReader( p.getInputStream );
  br = new BufferedReader( isr );

  while( (line = br.readLine()) != null ) {
    input += line + "\n";
  }

} catch( Exception e ) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString(java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

If I well understood your problem, you are looking for a popen-equivalent function in Java. Maybe this discussion can help you :)

[Java: popen()-like function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887658/java-popen-like-function)

Comment: Emanuele Parisi, question is not about searching- question about usage

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding `\n` in the end of line, stream should be closed
thus after replacing

```
IOUtils.write("1" + System.lineSeparator(), processOutputStream);
```

with

```
IOUtils.write("1", processOutputStream);
processOutputStream.close();
```

Code became work properly