# How to execute a .exe file and pass parameter to it .application is TreeScan( TreeScan.org)

Tags: java

I want to process the data using `treescan.exe` for that I have one `.tre` file and one `.cas` file.Now we have make a .prm file from these two file .i want to execute this .prm file .I don't understand how to write a java program give input on `treescan.exe` to give this .prm file as input. I am just able to run the `.exe` file then I don't understand how to process further.

Here is the file format:

**test.tre**

```
00869   09.01

00947   09.01

00703   09.01

00329   09.01

00245   09.01

00102   09.01

00581   09.01

00409   09.01

09.01   09

09
```

**test.cas**

```
00102 45 95

00245 12 39
```

I have only written the code for open the `.exe` file. Please help if some body knows how to process.

```
public class ProcessExe {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, AWTException {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        Runtime runtime=Runtime.getRuntime();
        try{
            Process process=runtime.exec("C://Program Files/TreeScan/TreeScan.exe");

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: if Treescan is supposed to process the data, why are you trying to write code to process the data?

Comment: Have you tried using backslashes in the file path, like `"C:\\Program Files\\TreeScan\\TreeScan.exe"`?

Comment: from our application what ever the data we are generating we need to process the data through treescan for analysis.

Comment: – deHaar exe is open through program .i want to know how to pass these files to it

Comment: Then don't try to start the process another time, it won't pass values to the existing process...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running an executable command in Java with parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963232/running-an-executable-command-in-java-with-parameters)

Comment: Piro, i have already seen this.

Comment: Process p = new ProcessBuilder("                                                             C://Program Files/TreeScan/TreeScan.exe","D://data/test1.prm").start();